# How to get Sharepoint user by Title using REST?

Tags: rest, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-api

I'm trying to search for a given user on a Sharepoint site using "lastname, firstname".  I was able to use the following url to get the total list of site users as a large XML document:

`https://thissite.com/sites/thatsite/_api/web/siteusers/`

However, I haven’t been able to figure out how to search by Title.  When I use the following url:

`https://thissite.com/sites/thatsite/_api/web/siteusers/getbytitle(“lastname,%20firstname”)`

I get this error:

```
<m:error xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ado/2007/08/dataservices/metadata">
<m:code>
-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException
</m:code>
<m:message xml:lang="en-US">
The expression "web/siteusers/getbytitle("lastname, firstname")" is not valid.
</m:message>
</m:error>
```

When I use the following url to get the same user's data:

`https://thissite.com/sites/thatsite/_api/web/siteusers/getbyid(41)`

Then I successfully get XML returned with that user's data.

I guess I could just parse the list obtained from `/siteusers` and load it into a searchable data object, but I was hoping for something more direct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`UserCollection` resource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531432.aspx#bk_UserCollection) does not expose `getbytitle` method, that's the reason why you get this exception.

In order *filter user by title* you could utilize [`$filter` query option](http://www.odata.org/documentation/odata-version-2-0/uri-conventions/#FilterSystemQueryOption) as demonstrated below:

```
https://contoso.sharepoint.com/_api/web/siteusers?$filter=Title eq '<Title>'
```